# How to access clipboard in VS 2017 extension project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsix

I try to interact with windows clipboard via SVsUIHierWinClipboardHelper using this code:

```
var dataObject = new OleDataObject();
dataObject.SetText("sometext"); 
clipboardHelper.Copy(dataObject);
```

but it has no effect. How to copy a simple text to clipboard correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use .NET [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=netframework-4.7.2) class:

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText("sometext");
```